# Proving Irrationality for powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

How to prove irrationality for $x$ if $4^x = 5$.
I think the way to go is proof by contradiction but I got stuck on trying to solve it.

Comment: If $4^{\frac{p}{q}}=5,$ then $4^p=5^q.$ Can you fill in the details?

Comment: No, I have not encountered a proof like that.

Comment: But that would work, wouldn't it?  If $4^{\frac pq}=5$ then $4^p=5^q$ would be undeniable wouldn't it?  If we assume $p$ and $q$ are both positive integers we get $4^p$ is even and $5^q$ is odd.  So we must have one of them $0$ or negative and that... well, it just won't work, will it.  That's right there in your lap.  Hit it with your paddle.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with the discussion that has already started on this question: $4^p = 5^q$ where $p,q$ are positive integers. The left hand side is an even number while the right hand side is an odd number. So they can't equal. So there is no number $\dfrac{p}{q}$ that satisfies this equation. And hence there is no rational solution!

Comment: Well, the left hand side can be $1,$ but $q$ cannot be $0.$ Easier to state in the general case using unique factorization.

Comment: $4 < 5$ so $4^x = 5\implies x > 1$ so if $x\in \mathbb Q$ and $x > 0$ we can assume $x = \frac pq$ where $1\le q < p; q,p \in \mathbb Z$.  So $4^{\frac pq} = 5$ so $4^p = 5^q$ and $p\ge 1$ so $4^p$ is even and $q\ge 1$ so $5^q$ is odd.